# Generic Type Alias for NotRequired and Optional

Tags: python, python-typing, typing, python-3.11

In `typing.TypedDict`, there is a difference between fields being `NotRequired` and fields whose values are declared `Optional`. The first means that the key may be absent, the latter means the value on an existing key may be `None`.

In my context (working with mongodb), I do not want to differentiate this, and simply allow a field to be both `NotRequired` and `Optional`. This could be achieved by

```py
class Struct(TypedDict):
    possibly_string = NotRequired[str | None]
```

In my context I never want to differentiate this, so I would like to have a generic type, say `Possibly[T]` which I can use as a shorthand for writing `NotRequired[T | None]`.

When I try to write a generic alias, mypy gives me the two errors indicated in the code comments:

```py
from typing import NotRequired, Optional, TypeVar, TypedDict

T = TypeVar("T")

Possibly = NotRequired[Optional[T]]


class Struct(TypedDict):
    possibly_string: Possibly[str]  #  Variable "Possibly" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]


non_compliant: Struct = {"possibly_string": int}
compliant_absent: Struct = {}  # Missing key "possibly_string" for TypedDict "Struct"  [typeddict-item]
compliant_none: Struct = {"possibly_string": None}
compliant_present: Struct = {"possibly_string": "a string, indeed"}
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want? If so, how?

I look for a solution for Python3.11 or upwards.

Comment: I don't think it is, because _"`NotRequired[]` can be only used in a `TypedDict` definition"_

Comment: If you mark it as a TypeAlias, which should be your default when defining type aliases (well, if not that "fancy" PEP695), `mypy` will emit much more useful error: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=8ab3acd2c643f3d91a85dabd6eb9e059

Comment: If you have enough such fields, I'd probably forget `NotRequired` and use the older totality flag: make a base with required fields, then subclass with `total=False` metaclass argument and add all optional fields (now without `NotRequired` - only `field: YourType | None`).

Comment: You can't do this in the standard typing system. If you're only using mypy, consider writing a [mypy plugin](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html).

Comment: @dROOOze Thanks for pointing me into that direction. Do you have experience with mypy plugins? I tried to write it, but I got stuck. If you would like to help me, here is my follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77968372/mypy-plugin-for-replacing-custom-typealias-with-notrequired